# Pushed view controller does not cover entire screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have created a application which displays the contacts in my device in a table view and when i click a row it will display the details of that contact on another view. This is how the storyboard looks like:
[image]

In my didSelectRowAtIndexPath i have this code:

```
NewViewController *WVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:WVC animated:YES];
```

When i run the application, the app looks like:

[image]

However when i click on a row the details are displayed, but like this:

[image]

Can someone let me know where i am going wrong, thanks in advance.

Code in NewViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 20)];

 mylabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 125, 300 , 20)];

[nameLabel setText:@"Name :"];
[mylabel setText:_LabelText];
[self.view addSubview:nameLabel];
[self.view addSubview:mylabel];

myPhonelabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 175, 300, 20)];
[myPhonelabel setText:@"Contact Number :"];
PhoneLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 20)];
[PhoneLabel setText:_phoneNumber];
[self.view addSubview:myPhonelabel];
[self.view addSubview:PhoneLabel];

myEmailLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 240, 300, 20)];
[myEmailLabel setText:@"Email ID :"];
EmailLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 265, 300, 20)];
[EmailLabel setText:_emailId];
[self.view addSubview:myEmailLabel];
[self.view addSubview:EmailLabel];

myBdayLabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 315, 300, 20)];
[myBdayLabel setText:@"Date Of Birth :"];
BdayLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 335, 300, 20)];
[BdayLabel setText:_birthDate];
[self.view addSubview:myBdayLabel];
[self.view addSubview:BdayLabel];

myButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 30)];
[myButton setTitle:@"Contact Details" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xBD/255.0 green:0xBE/255.0 blue:0xC2/255.0 alpha:1];
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
myButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
}
```

**EDIT: (ANSWER)**
After a lot of head banging and hair pulling, the problem was solved by replacing

```
NewViewController *WVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];
```

with

```
NewViewController *WVC = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
```

Honestly i don't know why the previous one didn't work.

Comment: What is frame of your view which you display contact detail.?

Comment: are you used the any additional view in your view controller

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the view i am trying to push does have some labels and buttons(created programmatically), but does that matter ?

Comment: @yankitPatel - I didn't get you, sorry i am a newbie.

Comment: ya sure your labels and buttons does not the probelm , the problem is in your view frame check once bro

Comment: please attach your code here...... so i can explain you...

Comment: @yankitPatel - code in second view controller ?

Comment: yes code in second view controller..

Comment: @yankitPatel - i have updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: put a some background color of second view controller on viewDidAppear() method. You need to debug first whether it is happening from your code by any way.

Comment: reset ur view constraints of NewViewController in storyboard

Comment: i think it is perfect code...there are no issue in their code..

Comment: @vaibby - no constraints were set, everything is default.

Comment: check preview of viewcontroller in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need navigation bar, use to hide it

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```